# Multithreading where when a thread finished it immediately start without waiting

Tags: python, multithreading

So I just started learning python threading and wondering can I immediately start a thread when it finished without waiting for another. I wrote a simple code below to test out where every thread will be executed 10 times.

```py
def thread_func(id):
    logging.info("Thread {} is starting at {}".format(id, datetime.now().time()))
    if id == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        logging.info("Thread {} ends at {}".format(id, datetime.now().time()))
    elif id == 1:
        time.sleep(3)
        logging.info("Thread {} ends at {}".format(id, datetime.now().time()))
    elif id == 2:
        time.sleep(5)
        logging.info("Thread {} ends at {}".format(id, datetime.now().time()))

for i in range(10):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        executor.map(thread_func, range(3))
```

In this case thread 1, 2 and 3 will run at the same time but thread 1 will start again after thread 3 has finished. I want thread 1 to start immediately after it finish and same for thread 2 and 3.

edit: This solution is solved thanks to Michael! Below is the updated code

```py
def thread_func(id):
    for i in range(3):
        logging.info("Thread {} is starting at {}".format(id, datetime.now().time()))
        if id == 0:
            time.sleep(1)       
        elif id == 1:
            time.sleep(3)
        elif id == 2:
            time.sleep(5)
        logging.info("Thread {} ends at {}".format(id, datetime.now().time()))

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    executor.map(thread_func, range(3))
```

Comment: First of all: A thread can't run twice. You must create a new thread. A simple approach would be to create in a thread 1 a new thread 2 immediately before thread 1 terminates. Thread 2 may then wait for termination of 1 (`join()`) and then continue.

Comment: Much simpler: Make a loop in the code to be executed by the thread.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks! Just exactly what I needed! I'll update the solution in my question.